# Displaying static image in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'd like to display a static image in a GridView.  I have the following:

```
<asp:GridView runat="Server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
  <asp:ImageField DataImageURLField="./images/myimage.png"/>
  <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="link" DataNavigateUrlFields="linkid" DataNaviateUrlFormatString="~/index.asp?q={0}" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Which results in the error:

*A field or property with the name './images/myimage.png' was not found on the selected data source.*

Basically I'm displaying the same image to the left of each hyperlink.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use a `TemplateField` inside `GridView`

```
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Image">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/myimage.png" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```